# error in ado.net entity data model

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net website, i set my data model **Code Generation Strategy : Default** to access the namespace
and also I could use the **addto methods**... for example **myEntities.AddToPatient(*******)**
but now AddTo methods and a lot of methods gone!!! and can't be recognize!!
I get this error :

> The type 'Patient' is not attributed with EdmEntityTypeAttribute but is contained in an assembly attributed with EdmSchemaAttribute. POCO entities that do not use EdmEntityTypeAttribute cannot be contained in the same assembly as non-POCO entities that use EdmEntityTypeAttribute.

I know this is a duplicate question, but I searched and still can't find a way to figure it out how this is turned into this!!!

this is all of mycode for one button click...

```
StoreEntities myEntities = new StoreEntities();
    {
        var search = from a in myEntities.Patients
                     where a.FirstName.Contains(NameTB.Text)
                     && a.LastName.Contains(LastNameTB.Text)
                     && a.PhoneNumber.Contains(TelTB.Text)
                     select a;
        GridView1.DataSource = search;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: In debug mode, it's stops at "(( var search = from a in myEntities.Patients ))"

Comment: I just delete the Model.tt and Model.context.tt.. and for now is working...